# How to attach multiple callbacks to an YouTube API event

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to attach callback to YouTube API event. Let's say there are two independent scripts on scripts on a site - mine and 3rd-party. Both are using JavaScript YouTube API. I need to run piece of code when API is ready. Here are examples of code:

3rd-party script:

```
// maybe load YouTube JS API
if (typeof window.YT === 'undefined') {
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = '//www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}

// initialize when API is ready
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
  // do some cool stuff here...
}
```

Mine script, absolutely same:

```
// maybe load YouTube JS API
if (typeof window.YT === 'undefined') {
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = '//www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}

// initialize when API is ready
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
  // do some cool stuff here...
}
```

In this case only one callback will be fired - last one, because it overwrites callbacks assigned before.

So, what programming technique I have to use here to safely attach my callback?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the YouTube API does not implement a standards compliant event-model (i.e. there is no `addEventListener("YouTubeIframeAPIReady", function () { })` available).

One option would be storing your callbacks in an array, and then just calling your callbacks from the single event handler callback you have available, like this:

```
var onYouTubeIframeAPIReadyCallbacks = [];

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
    var args = arguments;

    onYouTubeIframeAPIReadyCallbacks.forEach(function (callback) {
        callback.apply(this, args)
    });
};
```

And then instead of using `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`, you just push your callbacks to this array like this:

```
onYouTubeIframeAPIReadyCallbacks.push(function () {
    // ...
});

onYouTubeIframeAPIReadyCallbacks.push(function () {
    // ...
});
```

And so on...

So when the event handler is actually called, it will call all of your callback functions in your array.